Help needed with understanding Arnold's proof of Abel-Ruffini Theorem
I am trying to understand Arnold's proof with this document and this video.
In section 5 the existence of the permutation (1 2 3 4 5) in the set of commutator loops is used to conclude that any quintic formula must contain nested radicals. This reasoning is then repeated again and again to obtain Theorem 9. I think I have understood the reasoning but just want to check here.
The same logic is used in section 4 to show any cubic formula must contain nested radicals. My understanding so far is this:
Am I correct in saying that the proof of exercise 1 is that the point $p$ ends up without any phase change after travelling a commutator of loops and is therefore on the same branch, so, $f(p)^\alpha$ (for rational $\alpha$) doesn't change from its original value before $p$ travelled the loop. The continuity of the function means that $f(p)^\alpha$ must have also travelled a loop. This would be true for any commutator if the cubic formula had only one root.
However, in exercise 2 right after, it is shown that there exists a commutator that induces the permutation (1 3 2), which would not be a loop in the root space for any cubic formula. So, the cubic formula cannot have a single radical like in exercise 1, it must have $ >1$ radicals so there must be a nesting of radicals in the cubic formula.
Now in section 5, it goes on to find (1 2 3 4 5) as a permutation induced by a commutator, so, again, there must be a nesting of roots. Then, we prove that if there is a nesting of two roots, a commutator of commutators on the coefficients would induce a loop in the root space. Since after a commutator is applied, the phase of the point in coefficient space doesn't change, at the end of a series of applications of commutators, the point in coefficient space is still on the same branch as it started, so the result of an expression with nested roots:

$(f_{1}(p) + (f_{2}(p))^{\alpha_{2}})^{\alpha_{1}}$

would also return to its original value meaning a loop in root space was completed. This would mean that any commutator of commutators would result in a loop so no nontrivial permutation of the roots could be produced by a commutator of commutators. However, since (1 2 3 4 5) IS induced by a commutator of commutators, there must be a nesting of $>2$ radicals. We also see that as we apply commutator after commutator after commutator, we get the same set of 60 permutations in which (1 2 3 4 5) exists, allowing us to apply the reasoning iteratively, giving us theorem 9

(Arnold, 1963?). For any positive integer N, any quintic formula built out of the field operations, continuous functions, and radicals must have nesting of level ≥ N.

Is my understanding correct or have I missed something? Also, what is so special about 5 that the 60 possible loops that exist as commutators keep repeating forever, no matter how many commutators of commutators of commutators you take you still get the same 60 permutations? Is this the link with symmetry and galois groups? What is a good resource to learn the Galois theory proof of this?
EDIT: Here is my updated understanding of the proof which also answers my question here.

Looking at the cubic formula, using the same notation as before, for some $p$ in the 3 dimensional function space we prove as above that there cannot be only a single radical in the cubic formula.
Then, suppose there is a double radical in the cubic formula, $\sqrt[\alpha_{1}]{f_{1}(p)+\sqrt[\alpha_{2}]{f_{2}}(p)}$. The reason we cannot use only one commutator is because it's actually possible for this expression to output a different value to what we started with. A single commutator means any phase picked up about the branch point where $f_{2}(p) = 0$ ends up being $0$, so the result of $\sqrt[\alpha_{2}]{f_2{p}}$ returns to the same value, however, this doesn't guarantee that no phase has been picked up around the branch point of the outer radical, where ${f_{1}(p)+\sqrt[\alpha_{2}]{f_{2}}(p)} = 0$.
So, we need a commutator of commutators to ensure no phase is picked up around either branch point, thus returning the value of $\sqrt[\alpha_{1}]{f_{1}(p)+\sqrt[\alpha_{2}]{f_{2}}(p)}$ to its original value, leaving an image of a loop. The same logic can then be used as before for the quartic and quintic (which have non trivial commuatators of commutators) but not the cubic since the only commutator of commutators is a trivial permutation meaning a loop was actually completed so radicals under radicals cannot be ruled out.
This logic is then just applied iteratively to the quintic where a tower of any height of commutators will always be capable of causing a non-trivial permutation, thus ruling out the possibility of there being a finite number of nesting levels.

As I'm writing this I've just realised that I can't actually think of any commutator that doesn't pick up any phase around one branch point but does pick up pahse around some other branch point. For any branch point, can't we say a commutator gains a phase (with respect to that branch point) of k (the first loop), then gains a phase of h (the second loop), then loses a phase of k and then h so total phase change is $k + h -k -h = 0$ for all branch points, leaving me back at the question why do we need commutator towers of height k for k level nesting where is the flaw in the logic of just using a single commutator, though this would result in the false conclusion that it is impossible to have double nested radical in the cubic formula?

Why did you tag this [tag:general-topology]?

My advisor V.B.Alekseev was a student of when Arnold was reading lectures on the topic and wrote a somewhat peculiar book based on these lectures (V.B.Alekseev "Abel's theorem in Problems and Solutions", https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/1-4020-2187-9), maybe it can be helpful to you

@J.W.Tanner https://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/THESES/Mereyn_Vrij_Bachelor_2022.pdf This paper had the title as topological proof so I thought this proof had something to do with topology. Sorry if I'm wrong, I can take the tag off if needed.

@VladimirLysikov Thank you, I'll try get hold of a copy.

I thought there was a longer, quite well done video on Arnold's proof put together by a Math.SE-er, who I want to say is from the British Isles somewhere, but I can't recall who it is or how to find the video. Does that ring a bell with anyone?

Ahh, it was not all wrong and the video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSHv9Elk1MU

Disclaimer: This is not really a answer but since I cannot comment I am writing it here.
A really clear source on Arnold-type proof of Abel (like the document and video you have linked above. I say 'type' because Arnold's proof is slightly different) is Paul Raymond, Abel-Ruffini's Theorem: Complex but Not Complicated! https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05162
Added
What is special about 5 is that when you have 5 things its possible to form an infinite chain of "commutators of commutators of ...". This is because for 5 distinct things its possible to write a 3-cycle as a commutator of 3-cycles. In general:
$$ [(i,j,k)(k,l,m)]=(jkm) $$
To review:
For quadratic equations, if we have a formula for the roots in terms of the coefficients it can't only be with the basic arithmetic operations because we can transpose the two roots continuously making the formulas give the same values at the end when they ought to have given the other (their values will follow a loop) so we need at least one-level of root extraction.
For cubic equations, if we have formulas for the roots in terms of the coefficients that only rely on basic arithmetic and one-level of root extraction then we can move the 3 roots as commutators of transposes so that the formulas give the same values at the end. That is, we need at least two levels of root-extractions.
Now suppose for quintic we have formulas for the roots in terms of their coefficient that involve the arithmetic ops, root extractions upto k-levels of nesting for some k. However, we have 5 roots so we can form a move with k+1 chain of commutators. Contradiction.
How this ties to group theory is the following:
A solvable group is a group which has a derived series of commutators ending with the trivial group. A finite solvable group has a finite series.
Let's call the space of polynomials with a fixed degree and except places where they don't have distinct roots $P_n$. The space of roots is a $S_n-$ principal bundle.
Since a closed loop in $P_n$ permutes its roots we have a map from the fundamental group to $S_n$.
Arnold's recasting of Galois' insight is that if the roots were to have formulas in terms of arithmetic ops and a finite level of nesting of root extractions then the image of the fundamental group would be solvable.

@streets_behind Thanks a lot for your answer, It also answered my question here about why you can't just use one commutator which induces a a non-trivial permutation and the same logic as with a single radical to show a double nested radical is also impossible in the cubic formula. There aren't enough characters to write this in a comment so I'll add it in as an update to this post.

I think this answer/comment is helpful; besides, it is too long to be a a comment.
